# Web service with ajax control and text box in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying this code to access a web service. I have also added a default page with text box control, but while running only the text box is visible. I've also added a database with proper path in web config but still it is not working. Please help me out. I'm trying to access it from my machine ip address but it's returning an error. Is it necessary to install?

```
public static List<string> getinfo(string prefixText)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select*from raj where firstname like +'%'", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", prefixText);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        List<string> firstname = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            firstname.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }
        return firstname;
    }
```

While running it's not returning any error.

Comment: Where do you get error? any exceptions?

Comment: r u getting any ans for this?

Answer (score 0):

You missed `@firstname` in command

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select*from raj where firstname like '%'+@firstname
+'%'", conn);
```

Or second way..

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select*from raj where firstname like @firstname", conn);         
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", "%"+prefixText+"%");
```

**EDIT:-**
Try this code..using SqlReader....

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
     conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select*from raj where firstname like  @firstname", conn);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname","%"+prefixText+"%");        
     List<string> firstname = new List<string>();


     using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            firstname.Add(reader[0].ToString());
         }             
         reader.Close();
     }
     connection.Close(); 
     return firstname;
```